How to use Inception V3 as Backbone for Vision Transformer?
I’m looking to create a Vision Transformer (ViT) using Inception V3 as the backbone. For an input image of size 500x500x3, Inception V3 outputs feature maps with dimensions [1, 2048, 14, 14].
How can I feed these feature maps into a ViT? I came across the ViTHybridForImageClassification class in huggingface transformers library, which seems relevant, but I’m unsure how to implement it with the Inception V3 backbone.
Here’s the code I used to extract the intermediate feature maps from Inception V3:
model = timm.create_model('inception_v3', pretrained=True, features_only=True)
x = model(torch.randn(1, 3, 500, 500))
print(x.shape)   # this returns torch.Size([1, 2048, 14, 14])

I want to model this tensor shape [1,2048,14,14] in such a way that, each channel to consider as a single patch of size 14x14, and their are 2048 patches. Use the channel attention between 2048 patches.
Any help would be appriciated.
